# UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayView can not be full screen on the iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, fullscreen

this is my code:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
overlay.alpha = 0.3;
overlay.clipsToBounds = NO;

UIButton *takePictureButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024)];
[takePictureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(takePictureButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
takePictureButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[overlay addSubview:takePictureButton];

picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
[takePictureButton release];
[overlay release];

_currentPicker = picker;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

And it's look like on iPad 2 with iOS 4.3.2:
[sorry, I can't post image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p439o.png)
What I want is it can take picture when user tap anywhere on the screen.
Forgive my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by myself:
just **reset the size** of cameraOverlayView **after** present UIImagePickerController.
code like this:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
picker.delegate = self;

UIButton *takePictureButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[takePictureButton addTarget:self action:@selector(takePictureButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

picker.cameraOverlayView = takePictureButton;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

takePictureButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024);

[picker release];
[takePictureButton release];
```

Although it's not elegant, but it work :)

Comment: It does not make any difference over here.